# Bash user input Mysql login

Tags: mysql, bash, mysql-error-1045

Will start with what I am trying to accomplish. I wrote up a menu script to add a new database and echo back to screen the results. But can't seem to get it to login with a variable.

Heres the part I am having problems with:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ "$yn" != "Yes" && "$yn" != "Y" && "$yn" != "y" && "$yn" != "yes" ]]; do
    echo "  Please, type password for root user.             #"
read -r  mysqlrp
    echo "  You have entered $mysqlrp as your MySQL password #"
    echo "  Is this correct? (Yes or No)            #"
      read yn
done
mysql -u root -p$mysqlrp
```

have also tried:

```
mysql -u root -p${mysqlrp}
```

as well as `mysql -u root -p'${mysqlrp}'`

I get the following:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

even though when I try without the script works fine.

Please help, 
Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: What error message do you get?
Are there any special characters in the password?
Did you try `mysql -u root -p"$mysqlrp"`?

Comment: tried it: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
yes there is special characters but it displays back to me correctly from 
    echo "  You have entered $mysqlrp as your MySQL password #"

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To supply a password directly in the command line string, you should use `mysql --password=[password]`. [See this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).

And to prompt the user for a password, you should probably use something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Username: " uname
stty -echo
read -p "Password: " passw; echo
stty echo
```

You must not ever print the password. And it should not be seen while typing it in either.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Username: " uname
stty -echo
read -p "Password: " passw; echo
stty echo
mysql --user=$uname --password=$passw
```

That script works for me. If it doesn't for you, please check that your mysql permissions allow you to login from `localhost`.

Comment: You can use `read -s` to suppress echoing of the characters as they're typed.

Answer (score 0):

In a shellscript, you can do

```
set -x
```

to see what the command being executed looks like.

You should prolly do mysql --password="$mysqlrp". '$mysqlrp' -> '$mysqlrp'.

In your real script, I suppose you probably want to do

```
read -p "Password, plz:" -s mysqlrp
```

In order to properly answer the question, the actual error you get would be helpful. [UPDATE: answered in comment.]

Also, note that if your query is longrunning, your password will be visible in "ps -ef"

Comment: ok here the problem is it is keeping the $mysqlrp as the password